# What is the purpose of having the forward declarations in the given fragment of C code?

Tags: c, cgi, forward-declaration

I have been assigned a task to maintain a legacy CGI program which adds data to a college database. This program is made up of a single file and is compiled without warnings. The file uses forward declarations as given below.

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 50

enum Grade;
enum Subject;
struct Student;
...

int lastErrorNo;

void addGrade (enum Subject subj, enum Grade g, struct Student *stud);
void editGrade (enum Subject subj, enum Grade g, struct Student *stud);
...

enum Grade {
    A = 0,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E
};

enum Subject {
    Calculus1 = 0,
    Calculus2,
    ...
    Mechanics
};

struct Student
{
    char lastName[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char firstName[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    ...
};

static int lastErrorNo = 0;

int main(void) {
    ...
}

void addGrade (enum Subject subj, enum Grade g, struct Student *stud)
{
    ...
}

void editGrade (enum Subject subj, enum Grade g, struct Student *stud)
{
    ...
}
```

I can't understand what is the purpose of the forward declarations of `Grade`, `Subject`, `Student` and `lastErrNo`? Why not to immediately replace them with their definitions?

Comment: so you can call `addGrade` etc.. from the `main` which is mysteriously _before_ them

Comment: You could enable a lot of compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`) and then remove the forward declarations and see if it breaks.

Comment: @MOehm They're not functions. `Grade` and `Subject` are `enum`, and `Student` is a `struct`.

Comment: @Barmar: Ah, okay. Being able to read helps, apparently.

Comment: It seems to me a likely explanation is that this file started out as a header file and a .c file, and someone merged them into the file that you now have. In the fragment shown, there is no need to forward declare these objects.

Comment: @AlexNicolaou The enums are being used in the function prototypes. So they do need to be forward declared, or the file needs to be rearranged into a sensible order.

Comment: @Alex Nicolaou So these forward declarations might be just the result of haphazard merging of several files with no actual rationale behind them?

Comment: KimHo00 that seems the simplest explanation to me. 

@user3386109 the OP already knows that they could move the declarations above first use, and is trying to come up with a rationale for forward declaring them needlessly _as opposed to declaring them up front_, not as opposed to not declaring them at all. The rearrangement you're talking about is exactly what the OP seems to want to do, but fears there is a rationale against.

Comment: @Alex Nicolaou Thank you. I wish I had your ability to express the things succinctly and directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I can't understand what is the purpose of the forward declarations of Grade, Subject, Student and lastErrNo?*

Abou the enums, the compiler must know the variables before you can use them, since you are using them in the functions forward declarations, the compiler needs to know what those types are.

The reason for the declaration of `int lastErrorNo;` globally maybe to keep as a global error flag, but since it's redeclared later as `static` also globally, the code won't compile due to the redeclaration, maybe a typo?

> *Why not to immediately replace them with their definitions?*

You could just define them before you use them instead of forward declaring. It's just a matter of code organization.

Comment: "It's just a matter of code organization". I gotta write it down in my programming notebook! Thank you!